# Updating entries in a matrix given a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
[[1.10629335 0.         2.21258671 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [1.25571599 1.25571599 0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [1.         1.41956932 1.49244153 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 2.10342705 0.         1.05171352]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

I want to go through each row and check if the entry is less than 1, if it is then I take that entry and add the entry to the right of it. For example,
suppose I have

```
[[ 0.5 ,  1]
 [0  ,   0]]
```

The first entry is 0.5 which is less than 0 thus we will now have

```
[[ 1.5 ,  1]
 [0  ,   0]]
```

I think that makes the example relatively clear. Now how do I apply that to the entire matrix I have?

This is what I tried:

```
def modify_PITI_nums(adjusted_PITI_nums1):
    for i in range(1,col_num):
        if adjusted_PITI_nums1.iloc[0][i] <1:

            return  adjusted_PITI_nums1.iloc[:,i]+ (adjusted_PITI_nums1.iloc[:,i+1] -1)
        else:
            return adjusted_PITI_nums1.iloc[:,i]



adjusted_PITI_nums1.apply(lambda row: modify_PITI_nums(row['nper_0']), axis = 1)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index a1')
```

Note that the `adjusted_PITI_nums1` is a dataframe with the matrix contents and headers look like this:

[image]

Comment: im confused. Speaking purely from how the data is stored, is this a matrix or a dataframe? are you looking for a numpy solution or is that no good.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It is a dateframe I just tried to explain from a maths persepective to make it clear. I think a numpy a solution is good as long as its not too slow.

Comment: isn't `adjusted_PITI_nums1` in `modify_PITI_nums` just a Series instead of a DataFrame, given the way you designed your lambda function?

Comment: `modify_PITI_nums` takes `row` as parameter, but you call it on `row['nper_0']` which is a float. Try `lambda row: modify_PITI_nums(row)`

Comment: @mommermi I am not sure if my lambda function is correct

Comment: @QuangHoang I dont think that is the issue in terms of the lambda function, it is the function modify_PITI_nums  that seems to be the problem

Comment: You can say it that way. But you should not pass `row['nper_0']` because it is an `np.float`, and with only that number, you cannot know which/where to add the *right next* number.

Comment: @QuangHoang Okay, if you understand what I am trying to do could you provide an answer so that I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
def modify_row(row):
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        if row[i] < 0.5:
            row[i] += row[i+1]
    return row    

df = df.apply(lambda row: modify(row), axis=1)
```

input:

```
        0          1           2          3
0   0.939943    0.891797    0.491610    0.827307
1   0.500028    0.756851    0.545806    0.575469
2   0.880074    0.662705    0.205046    0.269572
3   0.970287    0.731664    0.528683    0.785946
```

gives:

```
        0           1           2           3
0   0.939943    0.891797    1.318918    0.827307
1   0.500028    0.756851    0.545806    0.575469
2   0.880074    0.662705    0.474618    0.269572
3   0.970287    0.731664    0.528683    0.785946
```

Notice the inputs in column 2.

---

Edit: `DataFrame.transform()` is a better candidate as it does not create a new dataframe. Also, parallel like `kmario23` works:

```
def modify_row(row):
    mask = row[:-1] < 0.5
    row[:-1] += row[1:]* mask

# raw = True makes row to be an np.array
df.transform(lambda row: modify_row(row), axis=1, raw=True)
```

Comment: Is that the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: It is not as `apply` is always slow, and we returned  the whole data frame. Depending on your data size that it feasible or not. But I am not sure how to make it faster. Pandas and numpy are not really made for elementwise operations like this anyway.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Scratch that, it can be faster with edit I just add.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a NumPy only solution which should work:

```
In [51]: arr  
Out[51]: 
array([[0.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0. ]])

# generate a boolean mask
In [52]: mask = (arr < 1)
Out[52]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])

# go over all the columns and check for condition
In [53]: for col in range(mask.shape[1]): 
    ...:     if np.all(mask[:, col]): 
    ...:         arr[:, col] = arr[:, col] + arr[:, col+1] 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         continue 

In [54]: arr          
Out[54]: 
array([[1.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0. ]])
```

Note: This approach assumes that all the values in a particular column are less than the ones on the right.